# Label field with just an image

Tags: blackberry

How can I add a Field that is just an image ? I;ve being try to override paint in LabelField but its not working -

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.EncodedImage;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;

    public class CustomLabelField extends LabelField{

        private EncodedImage image;

        public CustomLabelField (EncodedImage image){

            super("",HCENTER | ELLIPSIS );     
            this.image = image;     
        }        

        public void paint(Graphics graphics){
            graphics.drawImage(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image, 0, 0, 0);  
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the [BitmapField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BitmapField.html)? If you only need an image this is the object to use.

Comment: It needs to be an image object. Unfortuantely I'm unable to use BitmapField.

Comment: What do you mean? BitmapField takes an EncodedImage, which is what you're using.

Comment: I didnt see the setImage method on the bitmap object, was just looking at the constructor. Thanks!